# Java cant make TempListener work

Tags: java, swing, class, graphics

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
private JTextField xField, yField, diameterField;
private JButton Redraw;
private JLabel xLabel, yLabel, rLabel;
Circle myCircle = new Circle (150, 150, 30, Color.red, Color.white);
Graphics g;
//Paint objects on panel
public void paintComponent (Graphics page) {
super.paintComponent(page);
g = page;
myCircle.draw(g);
}

public CirclePanel(){
    xLabel = new JLabel("X= ");
    yLabel = new JLabel("Y= ");
    rLabel = new JLabel("R= ");

    xField = new JTextField(5);
    xField.addActionListener(new TempListener());

    yField = new JTextField(5);
    yField.addActionListener(new TempListener());

    diameterField = new JTextField(5);
    diameterField.addActionListener(new TempListener());

    Redraw = new JButton("Redraw!");
    Redraw.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    add(xLabel);
    add(xField);
    add(yLabel);
    add(yField);
    add(rLabel);
    add(diameterField);
    add(Redraw);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setBackground(Color.white);
    }
  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

        //Update page
        myCircle.draw(g);
        //repaint panel
        repaint();
        }
    private class TempListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            int x, y, newbase, newhei;

            String text = xField.getText();
            String text2 = yField.getText();

            x = Integer.parseInt (text);
            y = Integer.parseInt (text2);


            myCircle.draw(g);

            repaint();





        }

    }
}
}
```

Hi guys I'm tring to make java application that draw a circle and redraw it with the new values that are in JTextField. I wrote three class for it. One of them is contain accessor, mutators, constructor. one of the class has the main method of course and a one of the class is above. But TempListener not working. Can you help me?

Comment: Please explain your problem as if we don't know what you're trying to do. You say that "TempListener is not working" but what is it supposed to do? You seem to be assuming that we've read your entire assignment and can read minds. We can't.

Comment: Don't use a Graphics field in your class. Use the local Graphics object inside of paintComponent only. In other words, get rid of your `g` variable, and your TempListener ActionListener should not be calling any methods off of g, and shouldn't even see a Graphics object. It should just change variable state and call repaint. Read the graphics tutorials for more on this. [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should get the Graphics field, g, out of your program. Instead use the local Graphics variable, the one you call `page` inside of your paintComponent method, but don't use it anywhere else.

Suggestions:

- Have your ActionListener make changes to the state of the myCircle object, your code does not do this.
- Then have it call `repaint()`.
- Get this, `myCircle.draw(g);` out of your ActionListener as it doesn't belong there.
- Read the Swing graphics tutorials: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: I copied and paste to eclipse to help me more than JCreator and ecplipse says The type CirclePanel.ButtonListener.TempListener is never used locally. So my problem turned out my program cant find templistener(I do'nt know how and why) dou you have any idea?